# Python implementation of non uniform (non linear) x-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, axes

I am trying to have a non linear x - axis in Python using matplotlib and haven't found any functions or hack arounds to this problem.

This is how our [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKS1u.png) looks at this point of time and I want to convert it to something like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41ggK.jpg) (Look at the difference in x axes of both graphs)

The code I have as of now is:

```
plt.axis([0, 100, 0, 1])
plt.plot(onecsma_x, onecsma_y, label='1-CSMA')
plt.plot(slotted_aloha_x,slotted_aloha_y, label ='Slotted Aloha')
plt.plot(pure_aloha_x,pure_aloha_y, label ='Pure Aloha')
plt.plot(npcsma_x, npcsma_y, label ='Non persisten CSMA')
plt.plot(pcsma_x, pcsma_y, label ='P persistent CSMA')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For log x-axis use `semilogx` instead of `plot`.

Also you could limit the x-axis maybe after using `semilogx` (but before `show`) with:

```py
plt.xlim(0, 10**2)
```

Comment: Using 0 in a log axis isn't a good idea. Better 0.0001 or so, depending on the application. Log(0) is minus infinity, so the 0 is impossible to position on the log axis.

Comment: @JohanC Realized that at the start and started from 0.01 instead of 0. Thanks anyways!